# Unreachable statement in colorAnimation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Before I start, I just want to let you know I'm new to Android programming so this question might actually be a bit silly.
In my `mainActivity.java` file I've got a tabbed layout using 3 `viewPager` fragments: `fragment1`, `fragment2`, and `fragment3`.
I want the background color of the window to change smoothly when the second fragment comes in and to do that I've got a valueAnimator from the color animation:

```
public class fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout2, null);

        int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFrame2);
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                getView().findViewById(R.layout.fragmentlayout2).setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());

            }

        });
        colorAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the program it returns an `unreachable statement` error about the colorFrom statement. I've tried solving it but it just won't go away! Any help appreciated!

Comment: nothing after `return` will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `return` at the end of `onCreateView` because `return` will send back the control and won't go further

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFrame2);
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                getView().findViewById(R.layout.fragmentlayout2).setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());

            }

        });
        colorAnimation.start();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout2, null);
    // ^^^^^^^^
    }
```

Comment: @runfel i am glad that i could help,happy coding